# Webkit as a Win32 API control

Tags: windows, webkit

Has anyone tried to wrap the webkit browser widget into a simple Win32 C control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a COM API maintained by Brent Fulgham that is the standard apple webkit COM api, using  Curl, Cairo and CFLite for the backend.  You can get details at http://whtconstruct.blogspot.com/2009/09/updated-webkit-sdk-r48212.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at this time.

Comment: Er, why? It was successfully wrapped as a WPF control; I doubt wrapping it in a bunch of functions callable from C would be any harder than that. It hasn't been done yet, perhaps, but "not possible"? I don't think so.

Comment: Then I am mistaken. What is the WPF project called?