# How to render a string containing HTML into an image in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, image

I am developing a web application that has an interactive feedback tool for users. In this application users can click a send feedback button. The button puts up an overlay over their current web page and allows them to drag highlight area `DIV`s to emphasize certain areas. Once they submit their feedback the HTML of the entire page is passed via AJAX back to the server.

Once on the server I now have a string containing the HTML of the page. From here I would like to run this string through some sort of engine that renders the HTML and builds an image. A sort of round about way of taking a screenshot if you will.

How might one accomplish something like this? Are there engines available that are written in C# and can build up the HTML and render an image?

Comment: Option 1, see Dillie's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334532/render-html-as-an-image

Comment: @DustinDavis Isn't that a web forms control? This is a web application.

Comment: @Alex Ford, what about the css styles for that HTML string? Are you thinking in render the pure HTML?

Comment: @hamlin11 I'm not sure how that helps me, can you explain? What is this magic code she speaks of? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Tocco, Good question. I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: So I think that you are trying to use a Web browser layout engine/rendering engine ...

Comment: @Tocco, ideally yes. I'm trying to emulate the functionality of Google Plus' send feedback system.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using Gecko ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this framework - http://awesomium.com/

This is exactly what you need.

Set the base URL, this will be needed to resolve any relative URLs

```
WebCore.SetBaseDirectory("C:\\MyApplication\\MyBaseDirectory");
```

Then load the HTML -

```
myWebView.LoadHTML("<p>Hello World!</p>");
```

Then use the .Render() method, and you'll be able to save the rendered content to an image.

Comment: D: except not for $2900!!! Dang... Sadly our company makes a lot more than $100k but I know they will not spring for $2900 because what I want it for is relatively simplistic.

Comment: It looks like if I want to go the cheap route I'm going to have to stick to the way Google+ does it and use the `canvas` tag in HTML 5 to draw a screenshot. Then just limit the functionality in HTML 4 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider usin LLMozLib if you want to go by Gecko.
See more details [here](http://ubrowser.com/)

EDIT

There's an ActiveX control to embed Gecko on Windows.
[Sample here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/embedding/browser/activex/tests/csbrowse/)

EDIT

I got it working on a Windows Forms application.
Using [these resources](http://code.google.com/p/leapin-lizard/downloads/list).
It is a csharp wrapper to Gecko ...

That's my sample code ...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\Users\esouza\Downloads\xulrunner"); //Tell where are XUL bin
        InitializeComponent();
        //geckoWebBrowser1 is an instance of GeckoWebBrowser control that I've dragged on the Form1
        geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new EventHandler(geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }

    void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(geckoWebBrowser1.Width, geckoWebBrowser1.Height);
        geckoWebBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle { X = 0, Y = 0, Width = 800, Height = 600 });
        b.Save("file.bmp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question and I've not got a silver bullet for you.

You're surely going to need a browser engine of some description and then capture the rendered output as a bitmap.

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474466/webkit-as-a-win32-api-control) that there was a COM wrapper developed for WebKit. Maybe that's a good starting point.